# MySQL push changes

Tags: mysql, replication

I'd like to be able to replicate a bunch of mysql tables to a custom service.

Right now, my best idea is creating an after insert trigger on each table and have these push to a 'cache' table that will get polled by my custom service for updated rows.

The problem with the above is that it means I have to poll at regular intervals. I'm wondering if there is a way to do it where mysql pushes updates to my service. The best way for this that I can think of is if triggers could support actions other than updating other tables, like doing a POST (which as far as I can tell is not possible).

I'm pretty sure there's a way to have mysql push binary logs to me somehow, but I dont know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the engine to run system code from your function.  Here's [an overview](http://bernardodamele.blogspot.com/2009/01/command-execution-with-mysql-udf.html).

Given this effort (setup and maintenance), a polling script doesn't look too bad.